# QGIS - Android, loading a .tif file

Tags: qgis, raster, android

I have a .tif file I would like to use as my base map on the Android version of QGIS. However, when I try and load it as a raster layer, it states that this is not a correct raster source.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Is Tiff (.tif) supported by Android? http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9587 try .png